# Java import jgoodies.forms.factories.* cannot be resolved. (Eclipse Luna)

Tags: java, eclipse, jgoodies

I've inherited code that uses:

```
import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.FormFactory;
```

I'm attempting to build the project.

I've added the `jgoodies-forms-1.8.0*.jar` files to a 'lib' directory that I made at the same level as the 'JRE System Library' and 'Referenced Libraries' within my Project.

```
/project
|-- src
|   `--(...)
|-- JRE System Library
|-- Referenced Libraries
`-- lib
    |-- jgoodies-forms-1.8.0-javadoc.jar
    |-- jgoodies-forms-1.8.0-sources.jar
    |-- jgoodies-forms-1.8.0-tests.jar
    `-- jgoodies-forms-1.8.0.jar
```

At the source files that use FormFactory, Eclipse Luna 4.4 tells me that:

```
The import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.FormFactory cannot be resolved.
```

I understand that this is because jgoodies RELEASE-NOTES.txt:

```
CHANGES IN 1.6.0
    o Renamed FormFactory to FormSpecs.
```

I figured I could just change "FormFactories" to "FormSpecs" but I get:

```
The import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.FormSpecs cannot be resolved.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package is wrong. According to [this](http://doc.formdev.com/jgoodies-forms/com/jgoodies/forms/layout/FormSpecs.html) `FormSpecs` is located in `com.jgoodies.forms.layout` package in 1.8. Assuming that you have the libraries correctly set-up in Eclipse, changing the package should work.

Or just remove the unresolved import and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to automatically organize the import statements.

Comment: Yes, of course!  I changed the import line to: `import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormSpecs`. And it worked just fine (after I installed the common library too).